# how to get alternative minimize effect in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I don't know if I saw this minimize effect in ubuntu but definitely have seen it on other nix systems.

It's basically a little button in the menu bar that when clicked, "minimizes" the window so that only the menubar shows. Really love this feature and was wondering if anyone knew the name of it or how to get it working on ubuntu.

thnaks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a application called "mediacity" or something like that...(I can't remember off hand...will try and find it later)

you can find it by installing [Ubuntu tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) which is good to have anyhow...

hope that helps till I can remember the name of that app

Comment: WOW thank you! For reference, in Ubuntu Tweak it is on the left side, Desktop > Window Management > Window Titlebar ACtions. SICKKK

Comment: glad that helped! installing ubuntu-tweak is ALWAYS the first thing I do

Comment: haha for good reason, it's so nice